# What are the two main ways to prove that a matrix $\Bbb R^{n\times n}$ is definite positive.

Tags: linear-algebra

What are the two main ways to prove that a real $n\times n$ matrix is definite positive?

Is the first way: If a matrix is $n \times n$ symmetric matrix, then the associated quadratic form is positive definite iff the eigenvalues of the matrix are all positive?

Comment: Have you had a look at the [entry of wikipedia about this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Characterizations)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from the wikipedia entry in the link jkn gave, your matrix is positive definite if and only if

"Its leading principal minors are all positive. The $k$th leading principal minor of a matrix $M$ is the determinant of its upper-left $k\times k$ sub-matrix. It turns out that a matrix is positive definite if and only if all these determinants are positive. This condition is known as Sylvester's criterion, and provides an efficient test of positive-definiteness of a symmetric real matrix."